# Simple query not pulling from database

Tags: php

I cannot figure this out, it's not an error as such, but when i try to echo out the results of a query:

```
  echo "SELECT * FROM `active_customers` WHERE `cus_email`='".$k."' AND `cus_product`='".$_GET['product']."'" . "<br />";
  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `active_customers` WHERE `cus_email`='".$k."' AND `cus_product`='".$_GET['product']."'");
  $a = mysql_fetch_array($r);
  $n = mysql_num_rows($q);
  echo "Number of rows:" . $n;
  echo $a['cus_id'];
  echo $a['cus_email'];
```

The number of posts is returning the correct number which is 1, these values **$a['cus_id'];** and **$a['cus_email'];** are not coming through at all, i even did a mysql query in phpmyadmin and it works there.

can anyone see what i have done wrong?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: in the sample, line 3 are wrong, change $r for $q

Comment: That was the problem! thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

correct code can be

```
echo "SELECT * FROM `active_customers` WHERE `cus_email`='".$k."' AND `cus_product`='".$_GET['product']."'" . "<br />";
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `active_customers` WHERE `cus_email`='".$k."' AND `cus_product`='".$_GET['product']."'");
$n = mysql_num_rows($q);
echo "Number of rows:" . $n;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  echo $row['cus_id'];
  echo $row['cus_email'];
}
```

Although i would recommend using mysqli or PDO for sql databases